# Git Fetch with Source:Destination vs Git Pull

Tags: git, branch

From all the questions regarding differences between fetch and pull, the answer is that fetch will update your copy of the remote and not merge anything into your local branch. But if you use the fetch command with source:destination say "git fetch origin development:development" it will update both the remote copy and the local copy. So what is the difference in this case between a pull and a fetch?

Answer (score 0):

> But if you use the fetch command with source:destination say "git fetch origin development:development" it will update both the remote copy and the local copy.

This isn't quite true.

One exception (which we can perhaps discount) occurs with Git versions predating 1.8.4, where `git fetch origin development:development` simply fails to update `refs/remotes/origin/development` entirely.  However, `git fetch origin development` *also* fails to update `refs/remotes/origin/development` here.  That's why I suggest discounting old versions of Git: they still behave the same way with respect to fetch-and-merge, as it were.  (Well, that, and they're really quite old.)

The more important exception, though, is when a fast-forward operation—a "fast forward merge", as `git merge` will claim it to be—is not possible or is prohibited through the `merge.ff` and/or `pull.ff` configuration variables or command line options.  This gets into the difference between a *fast-forward* and an actual merge.

When you have `git pull` run fetch-and-merge, the second Git command is, or is equivalent to, running an actual `git merge` command.  This command will:

- find the merge base commit(s) between `HEAD` and the merge target(s);
- then, consider whether a merge is possible and/or whether a fast-forward operation is possible and allowed.

A fast forward is possible and allowed when:

- the merge base is `HEAD`;
- there's one other commit to merge and `HEAD` is an ancestor of that commit; and
- neither the command line nor the configuration prohibit fast-forwarding.

In this case—the fast-forward possible-and-allowed case, that is—`git merge` will do that fast forward instead of merging, and in this case, `git fetch origin development:development` would also fast-forward the local branch name `development`.

But if a merge is possible, but fast-forwarding is prohibited or impossible, the `git merge` will do a real merge, while the `git fetch origin development:development` will simply fail to fast-forward the name `development`.  So here, the two commands differ.  Of course if you want your pulls always to fast-forward, and have configured `pull.ff` to `only` for instance, we're back to the operations being the same.

Well, *almost*.  There's still one more difference: `git pull`'s `git merge` will fast-forward the *current branch* (only), but `git fetch origin development:development` will fail if `development` *is* the current branch.  So you have to be on some other branch.  There is a way to make `git fetch` fast-forward the current branch (supply the `--update-head-ok` flag) but if you do this, you must use extreme caution as the updated branch name has not affected the index and work-tree, unlike a `git merge` driven fast-forward operation.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I only tested it where fast-forward was possible of course :-).